# Можно ли в JS вывести содержимое папки?

Tags: javascript

Задача: создать некий FolderViewer. Морда такая:

[image: FolderViewer]

Написал я это на PHP, используя функцию `scandir`, но заказчик не планирует это держать на веб-сервере, а хочет открыть **index.html** в браузере и всё.
Есть ли возможность сделать это client-side средствами, в частности JavaScript? Можно ли на JS вывести список папок и файлов внутри них? Все папки лежат на одном уровне с **index.html**

Comment: Можно, если будете собирать ваш сайт как `Electron` приложение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Вам потребуется node.js и [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) [fs.readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options)

Похожий вопрос был [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j)

Но получить доступ к файловой системе только средствами браузера без какого либо вэб-сервера у вас не выйдет.

Comment: Кажется, вы не ответили на вопрос ТС. Он просил только средствами браузера.

Comment: Ответил во второй части сообщения.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ничего стороннего устанавливать нельзя - всякие nodejs-ы, нужно чисто на js (ну или скачанные плагины типа name_of_plugin.js). Весь интернет кричит так нельзя! но надежда задать вопрос в stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko тот же Electron, который Вы предложили в своём комментарии к вопросу, работает поверх Node.js
DauletMyrzan Нельзя. По соображениям безопасности у браузера нет доступа к файловой системе.

Comment: @Ofer у вас немного устаревшая информация http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=49597 :)

Comment: @andreymal Это ещё на стадии обсуждения и нет информации когда будет поддержка в остальных браузерах. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/11/writable-files

Comment: @Ofer да, я знаю, как работает Electron. Дело в том, что для Electron не надо в явном виде устанавливать nodejs, Запускать его, настраивать. С точки зрения пользователя - запускаете файл - у вас все работает. Поэтому может и подойти ТС.

Comment: Доступ к папке как-то реализован в этом проекте https://vscode.dev/